How to webscrape elements using beautifulsoup properly?
I am not from web scaping or website/html background and new to this field.
Trying out scraping elements from this link that contains containers/cards.
I have tried below code and find a little success but not sure how to do it properly to get just informative content without getting html/css elements in the results.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://ihgfdelhifair.in/mis/Exhibitors'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, 'html')

What I am looking to extract (as practice) info from below content:

cards = soup.find_all('div', class_="row Exhibitor-Listing-box")
cards

below sort of content it display:
[<div class="row Exhibitor-Listing-box">
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="card">
 <div class="container">
 <h4><b>  1 ARTIFACT DECOR (INDIA)</b></h4>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Email : </span> artifactdecor01@gmail.com</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Contact Person : </span>                                                   SHEENU</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>State : </span> UTTAR PRADESH</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>City : </span> AGRA</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Hall No. : </span> 12</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Stand No. : </span> G-15/43</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Mobile No. : </span> +91-5624010111, +91-7055166000</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 11px;"><span>Website : </span> www.artifactdecor.com</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Source Retail : </span> Y</p>
 <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Vriksh Certified : </span> N</p>
 </div>

Now when I use below code to extract element:
for element in cards:
    title = element.find_all('h4')
    email = element.find_all('p')
    print(title)
    print(email)

Output: It is giving me the info that I need but with html/css content in it which I do not want
[<h4><b>  1 ARTIFACT DECOR (INDIA)</b></h4>, <h4><b>  10G HOUSE OF CRAFT</b></h4>, <h4><b>  2 S COLLECTION</b></h4>, <h4><b>  ........]
[<p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Email : </span> artifactdecor01@gmail.com</p>, <p style="margin-bottom: 5px!important; font-size: 13px;"><span>Contact Person : </span>        ..................]

So how can I take out just title, email, Contact Person, State, City elements from this without html/css in results?

i think you can use title.text() or email.text() . Been a while since I used beautifulsoup

@ManosKounelakis .text() is not working. Getting error like: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'... . Same with me.. I tried bs 5-6 years back only for couple of things.

As Manos Kounelakis suggested, what you're likely looking for is the text attribute of BeautifulSoup HTML elements. Also, it is more natural to split up the html based on the elements with the class card rather than the row elements, as the card elements correspond to each visual card unit on the screen. Here is some code which will print the info fairly nicely:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://ihgfdelhifair.in/mis/Exhibitors"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, features="html5lib")

cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="card")

for element in cards:
    title = element.find("h4").text
    other_info = [" ".join(elem.text.split()) for elem in element.find_all("p")]
    print("Title:", title)
    for info in other_info:
        print(info)
    print("-" * 80)


Thanks. It worked perfectly !!! The way I wanted. Appreciate your help for code & explanation.

No problem! Glad I could help :)

So text is a property not a function  right ?

@AlexDuchnowski This code does not reveal Contact Person (which is required)

@ManosKounelakis yes.

@ManosKounelakis Yes, that is my understanding. If you want a method instead, get_text() should work.
@SIGHUP Contact Person, email, state, and so on are included in other_info if they appear on the given card. Assigning them to variables as is done for title is a matter of simply searching for the relevant entries in the list.

@SIGHUP I am getting Contact Person in the results.

@ViSa It's a timing issue. The page in question is JavaScript driven which means that parsing the HTML is likely to be unreliable. selenium will offer more robust results.

The page you're scraping is rendered using JavaScript. What this means is that when you access the HTML from the HTTP(S) GET, it may not be completely ready for parsing.
You are likely to get better results if you use selenium which you could do like this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")
url = "https://ihgfdelhifair.in/mis/Exhibitors"

labels = {
    "email",
    "contact",
    "state",
    "city"
}

def text(e):
    if t := e.text.strip():
        return t
    if (t := e.get_attribute("textContent")) is not None:
        return t.strip()
    return ""

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    for card in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card"))):
        wait = WebDriverWait(card, 10)
        if title := wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h4"))):
            print("Title :", text(title))
        for p in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p"))):
            t = text(p).split()
            if t[0].lower() in labels:
                print(*t)
        print()

Sample output (incomplete for brevity):
Title : 1 ARTIFACT DECOR (INDIA)
Email : artifactdecor01@gmail.com
Contact Person : SHEENU
State : UTTAR PRADESH
City : AGRA

Title : 10G HOUSE OF CRAFT
Email : info@10ghoc.com
Contact Person : MR. SUSHIL KUMAR
State : UTTAR PRADESH
City : MORADABAD

Title : 2 S COLLECTION
Email : 2scollection@gmail.com,shariq@2scollection.com
Contact Person : MR. SHARIQ AHMAD SIDDIQUI
State : UTTAR PRADESH
City : MORADABAD


Thank you so much. I have always wondered how does scrapping work in case of javascripts. This is really great. Thanks for providing this alternate and better solution. Really really Appreciate your help !!!
